# Notary Services With Fault Tolerance (Database Oracle)

Tags: corda

How can I have notary services with fault tolerance using database oracle? Is there any recommendation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of Oracle RAC to create a HA notary has not been tested. In theory, any database that can be configured to have zero data loss can be used (if the DB doesn't guarantee zero data loss, i.e. it is not strongly consistent and/or doesn't have synchronous replication, data may be lost in failover, allowing double-spends). However, the MySQL HA notary implementation uses some MySQL-specific syntax that may not work with Oracle RAC.